# Why does the SUM function in MySQL get rid of several columns of data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a mock database that displays the equipment data for three separate game characters. When I run the following SQL I am able to pull up the full table

```sql
SELECT customerID, characters.characterID, characterName, headName, chestName, legsName, armsName
FROM characters
JOIN character_equipmentv ON characters.characterID = character_equipment.characterID
JOIN gear_head ON character_equipment.headID = gear_head.headID
JOIN gear_chest ON character_equipment.chestID = gear_chest.chestID
JOIN gear_legs ON character_equipment.legsID = gear_legs.legsID
JOIN gear_arms ON character_equipment.armsID = gear_arms.armsID
ORDER BY characterID
```

However when I add the `SUM` function to get the character's gearscore:

```sql
SUM(gear_head.gearScore + gear_chest.gearScore + gear_legs.gearScore + gear_arms.gearScore) AS gearScore
```

To the end of my SELECT statement, it only displays the first entry with the combined gearscore for every character! How can I fix this?

Comment: all aggregate function have this characteristic. what else you want

Comment: What do you want the output to be? The results of your first query with the sum being displayed in each row?

Comment: I was looking for a table of information with each of the respective characters' gear scores on their own character line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SQL Grouping](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-clause.htm).

Okay: `SUM` is an aggregate function and requires a `GROUP BY` clause to produce meaningful results based on another column.

Comment: Much appreciated! Group by fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

`SUM` is an aggregating function, that means is takes multiple rows and merges them.

Your SQL will tell you the sum of all the gear scores for all characterIDs

if you want the sum for a given characterID add `GROUP BY characterID` to the end of your query.